# Photo sharing web partI

Tags: web-part

I am looking for a way to upload a lot of photos to an external site (flickr would be preferable) and then display them in sharepoint online. Is there a web part or way to do this with javascript? I am not pleased with the photo gallery app built into sharepoint at all.

Comment: If there were, authentication/authorization would be a pain. Are you using the new document library experience, for photos it's decent.

Comment: my boss isn't a fan of the new experience. We are just looking to have a good gallery of photos